# make blank row appear 0 in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table containing Remarks as a column. Now i have to display the data inside remarks as 0 if the row is blank i.e empty but not Null. Please give me a query that will solve my problem in MS SQL server 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SELECT ... CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT remarksDisplay = CASE remarks WHEN '' THEN '0' ELSE remarks END
FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

use a case statement in your SQL i.e

```
select (case when Remarks = '' then '0' else Remarks end) as Remarks from RemarksTable
```

You can further extend this to handle null values too if you want i.e

```
select (case when isnull(Remarks, '') = '' then '0' else Remarks end) as Remarks from RemarksTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
case column1
when '' then 'unknown'  /*empty*/
when ' ' then 'unknown' /*empty with space*/
end

FROM table
```